# Custom ordered list format

Tags: html

I tried to use ordered list `<ol>` and each list item `<li>` outputs as 1. 2. 3. ... etc, I want the output to be 1) 2) 3) ... etc, can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, but only with the more up-to-date browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera will work):

```
ol {
  counter-reset: listCounter;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: listCounter;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(listCounter) ")";
}
```

Comment: @FDisk: yes, did you read the first sentence? I imagine (though I don't have access in order to test) that it *should* work on IE 10 and, *possibly*, IE 9.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS counter and pseudo elements:

```css
ol li{
    list-style: none;
    counter-increment: myIndex;
}

ol li:before{
    content:counter(myIndex)") ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: +1 for an answer I agree with, posted ahead of me (answering via iPhone takes so much time...). Had you posted your demo/example CSS *here* I'd've probably deleted my own, so very tardy, answer in deference to yours.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that in future answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, the valid options are listed [>here<](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/list/ol.html).