# How do you hide the dot after the bullet number in an ordered list?

Tags: html, css

Initially, I thought I could use :first-letter in CSS, legacy browser support aside, but I don't think the bullet numbers technically exist in the DOM. Assume I'm not going to use bullet list images or background images.

So something like:

1. Apples
2. Bananas
3. Oranges

would become

1 Apples
  2 Bananas
  3 Oranges

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list/10887#10887), it appears that the answer is:

```
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol li { display: block; }
ol li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

**SEE ALSO**: http://jsbin.com/ukojo4/

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list/10887#10887 vote to close

Comment: also, set `list-style-type:none;` on the `<ol>` element to remove the existing numbers.

Comment: Also use `ol li` instead of just `li` to protect unsorted lists from this alteration. which would change bullets into 1.

Comment: There is a slight mistake, at counter-increment: item there is a missing ;

Answer (score 4):

One problem of the solution provided by Sean is that you loose the nice alignment of the numbers.

Another way to remove the dots is to simply hide them by placing something else above them:

```
ol li:before {
    content: ".";
    color: #fff;        // color it in white (or whatever background you have)
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;    // make it bigger.
    font-weight: bold;  // and bolder
    position: absolute; 
    left: 18px;         // horizontal offset
    line-height: 13px;  // vertical offset
}
```

You will probably need to play around with *left* and *line-height* in order to place the white dots correctly, depending on your actual paddings and margins.

See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/HGfty/

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer from another post. I was able to modify the fiddle there to get your answer

[Custom ordered list format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388632/custom-ordered-list-format)

**EDIT:** looks like sean already got to it. +1 for his answer.