# JavaScript update variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the noob question as I just picked up javascript today.

I'm trying to create and delete div's with javascript buttons, and I have that working fairly well.

However when I delete,for example, div #7, out of div 1-8 I need the text to change so that it doesn't look like

number: 1 
number: 2 
number: 3 
number: 4 
number: 5 
number: 6 
number: 8

This code adds the div at the end of the containing div xbox

```
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="xbox" id ="xbox1'+numItems+'">Number:  '+countBox()+'</div>
```

this code counts the amount of boxes already

```
    function countBox()
{
    var numItems = $('.Cbox').length;
    return numItems;

}
```

I've thought about just taking the div and setting the inner-html. But I figured I'd see if there is a better way to force the code to update the variable.

Comment: Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: Why two different classes, you're inserting `xbox` boxes, but counting `Cbox` boxes ?

Comment: I cant get jsfiddle to work :P http://jsfiddle.net/JygnV/1/

Answer (score 1):

So basically update the text of all the elements so they are in numbered order again after one is removed.

The `numItems` variable uses the length, so that's not an issue.

To update the text of the all the boxes you could do

```
$('.xbox').text(function(i) {
    return 'number: ' + (i+1);
});
```

Comment: Couldnt have put it better myself.

Comment: So then would I call this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

1. add text to your divs
2. add onclick functions and pass what div i.e., onclick="myFunction(0)"
3. Update the div text

   document.getElementById('yourID').innerHTML = "new text!";

full example

***HTML***

```
<div id="div 1" onClick('update(0)');>some text</div>
<div id="div 2" onClick('update(1)');>some text</div>
<div id="div 3" onClick('update(2)');>some text</div>
```

*** JavaScript ***

```
function update(column){
    //max number of divs from your example would be 8
    for(var i = column; i < MAX_NUMBER_DIV_HERE; i++){
        document.getElementById('div ' + i).innerHTML = i + "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an `ol` instead with a custom format? ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388632/custom-ordered-list-format))

Or if there is a small amount of numbers, `nth-child` with `text-before`?

```
#group div:nth-child(1):before { 
  content: "number: 1";
}

#group div:nth-child(2):before { 
  content: "number: 2";
}
```

Legacy support is not very good in both cases.